# 'of a tyrannous disposition' .. what does it modify?

Tags: idioms, prepositional-phrases

> The Iranian frontier official in this district was called Hurmuzd. He
>   was reputed irascible by temperament, ***of*** a tyrannous
>   disposition, particularly in relation to his Arab subjects;... ([Read
>   more](https://books.google.com/books?id=hvx9jq_2L3EC&pg=PA6&lpg=PA6&dq=The%20Iranian%20frontier%20official%20in%20this%20district%20was%20called%20Hurmuzd.%20He%20was%20reputed%20irascible%20by%20temperament,%20of%20a%20tyrannous%20disposition,%20particularly%20in%20relation%20to%20his%20Arab%20subjects&source=bl&ots=FcDPURD7Ev&sig=jp1sbIQuNFKEcnJgI7H2blaHxSg&hl=en&sa=X&ei=zIG2VNHpGszyUO38gdAO&ved=0CCEQ6AEwAA#v=onepage&q&f=false))

To which part of sentence the "of" refer?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In formal registers it is common to say that someone (or something) who *has* a particular attribute (a *quality* or *disposition* or *temperament* or *mien*, &c) is ***of*** [that quality].

This is an "information packaging" device which allows the writer to deploy the attribute as a modifying phrase instead of a full clause.

A similar device is employed in the first quality attributed to Hurmuzd, who is not reputed to 'have an irascible temperament' but to be *irascible **by** temperament*.

```
 He had the reputation of having an irascible temperament  
                          having  a tyrannous disposition  
                         ↓
          He was reputed             irascible by temperament
                                of a tyrannous disposition
```

Comment: Thank you. Your explanations are always very useful to me.